# Strange JS redirect & 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a new toolbar for this [site](https://www.birthinjurysafety.org/) and I get this really strange new tab / redirect when on mobile if I rotate the device and try to navigate through the toolbar.

```
https://www.birthinjurysafety.org/[object%20MouseEvent]&visitorId=a625aeab-d753-41bc-bd93-a9830020e101?__utma=236318866.1681129442.1540344287.1540346383.1540359074.2&__utmb=236318866.1.10.1540359074&__utmc=236318866&__utmx=-&__utmz=236318866.1540346383.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=142272497
```

Anyone know why JS would do this? Oddly enough the button that causes this strange new tab to open isn’t even a link itself. It just opens the next menu.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions! I’m really at a loss with this one.

The toolbar is built in vanilla JS. Except the button itself has some old jQuery dependent code that animates the button and shows the menu.

Comment: is it `[object%20MouseEvent]` you're asking about? somewhere you're using a mouseevent object thinking it is a string perhaps?

Comment: Right off the bat, if you load the page (on desktop chrome) and check the javascript console, there are errors.  That URL looks like something built with Javascript which may have tried to do an object to string conversion that may have gone sour.  Are you sure this problem is limited to mobile?